# Typescript conditional return types: object or array of objects based on params

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Tried to keep it concise. The problem is in `MyItemRepository.foo` - see inline comment.

```
class MyModel {}

class MyItem extends MyModel {
  getFoo() {}
  getBar() {}
}

interface IMyItemData {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

class MyRepository<MyEntity extends MyModel, IMyEntityData extends any> {
  protected getData(entities: MyEntity): IMyEntityData;
  protected getData(entities: MyEntity[]): IMyEntityData[];
  protected getData(entities: MyEntity | MyEntity[]): IMyEntityData | IMyEntityData[] {
    if (Array.isArray(entities)) {
      return this.getDataItems(entities);
    }
    return this.getDataItem(entities);
  }

  private getDataItem(entity: MyEntity): IMyEntityData {
    return null;
  }

  private getDataItems(entities: MyEntity[]): IMyEntityData[] {
    return [];
  }
}

class MyItemRepository extends MyRepository<MyItem, IMyItemData> {
  foo(surprise: MyItem | MyItem[]): IMyItemData[] {
    let item: MyItem;
    let items: MyItem[];

    const itemData = this.getData(item); // correctly resolves type to IMyItemData
    const itemsData = this.getData(items); // correctly resolves type to IMyItemData[]

    // here I get the error that 'no overload matches this call'
    const surpriseData = this.getData(surprise); // resolves type to IMyItemData & IMyItemData[]

    return castArray(surpriseData); // Lodash method
  }
}

const repo = new MyItemRepository();

const items = repo.foo(new MyItem()); // correctly resolves type to IMyItemData[]
```

Tried also to check instance in `MyItemRepository.getData` instead of checking whether an array was passed, but still the same problem.

```
protected model: ModelConstructor<Entity>;

protected getData(entities: MyEntity | MyEntity[]): IMyEntityData | IMyEntityData[] {
  if (entities instanceof this.model) {
    return this.getDataItem(entities);
  }
}
```

I do not want to use type guards is `MyItemRepository.foo` as I don't care about the return type of `MyItemRepository.getData`. Any way to achieve what I want without it?

Basically I want `surpriseData` to be resolved to `IMyItemData | IMyItemData[]`, not `IMyItemData & IMyItemData[]`. Don't really get where it's coming from.

Currently using a bit hacky solution:

```
const surpriseData = this.getData(castArray(surprise));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in an overloaded function is the implementation signature, so it's not considered as one of the overloads.  All that you need to do here is have that last line twice -- once as an overload and once as the implementation.

```
protected getData(entities: MyEntity): IMyEntityData;
protected getData(entities: MyEntity[]): IMyEntityData[];
protected getData(entities: MyEntity | MyEntity[]): IMyEntityData | IMyEntityData[];
protected getData(entities: MyEntity | MyEntity[]): IMyEntityData | IMyEntityData[] {
```

This says that if `entities` is either input type, then the data is either return type.  The overloads are applied from top to bottom so there is no concern about inadvertently widening the more specific types.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mL99AW)